# How to prove the solutions given are fundamental set of solutions without a given differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, homogeneous-equation, wronskian

We are tasked to prove the two solutions below are two fundamental set of solutions.
These are the two solutions given to us and nothing else.

$y_1(t) = t^{-1}$

$y_2(t) = t^{3/2}$

All  I've learn so far is that to prove the solutions are a fundamental set, first you have to test the solutions in the given differential equation and then proceed to compute for the Wronskian.

I'm thinking this could be an error and the equation is missing. Should I go ask my professor?

Comment: @Moo yes i am but is that enough to prove that the solutions are fundamental ?

Comment: @Moo thank you i was looking for some confirmation that the equation is missing. I should just go ahead and ask my professor and point out the error.